# Database and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have created a user-based wordpress website on a shared hosting.The problem I have is my plan includes 100GB of webspace and it allows me to create 25 databases (each 1GB) in the C-panel.
As I was looking at the main database I created for this wordpress website, I noticed its almost halfway full.
my hosting provider told me I could run up to 18 parallel databases.

Im actually new to wordpress and coding,can anyone here point me to the right direction on how I can have multiple databases for the same wordpress website?

Comment: You'll be better off searching for another provider with more space or an upgrade with the provider you are at the moment.

Comment: Yes, estimate a projection of your data growth over the next two years or so. Talk to your hosting provider to ask what are their options for hosting you. Then shop around with other providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress without any plugins does **not** allow you to use more than one database for a single install.

If there were a plug-in for multiple database usage, I'd carefully check its reviews, download count, and open issues before adopting it.

There's a plug-in called WP Clean Up I've used for years. It can substantially shrink your site's database size, by deleting old drafts of posts and other historic data, and optimizing the various tables. You may be able to use it to postpone your day of reckoning with this (silly silly silly) 1GiB limit. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clean-up/